# Проблема с шейдером (C# DirectX 9 HLSL)

Tags: c#, directx, шейдеры

Здравствуйте.

Начал изучение шейдеров в DirectX. Понимаю, что в сети много исходных кодов шейдеров, но никак не могу переступить порог вхождения.
Написал шейдер исходя из нескольких примеров, компилируется без ошибок, но объект, к которому он применен не рисуется.

Предполагаю, что косяк где-то в technique(она не была описана в примерах).

Вот код шейдера:

```
/* ========== ВЕРШИННЫЙ ШЕЙДЕР ========== */
float4x4 world_matrix; // мировая матрица
float4x4 view_matrix;  // матрица вида
float4x4 proj_matrix;  // матрица проекции
float4 light_position; // положение источника света

struct VS_INPUT // Входящие данные
{
    float4 Position: POSITION;
    float3 Normal: NORMAL;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT // Исходящие данные
{
    float4 Position: POSITION;
    float3 Light: TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal: TEXCOORD1;
};

VS_OUTPUT VS_Main(VS_INPUT vs_input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT OUTPUT = (VS_OUTPUT)0;
    // Произведение мировой, видовой и проекционной матриц
    float4x4 worldViewProj_matrix = mul(world_matrix, view_matrix);
    worldViewProj_matrix = mul(worldViewProj_matrix, proj_matrix);
    // Вычисляем позицию вершины
    OUTPUT.Position = mul(worldViewProj_matrix, vs_input.Position);
    //Сохраняем позицию источника света для передачи в пиксельный шейдер
    OUTPUT.Light = light_position;
    //Рассчитываем нормаль поверхности и сохраняем для пиксельного шейдера
    OUTPUT.Normal = normalize(mul(world_matrix, vs_input.Normal));
    return OUTPUT;
}

/* ========== ПИКСЕЛЬНЫЙ ШЕЙДЕР ========== */
float Diffuse_intens;
float4 Diffuse_color;

float4 PS_Main(float3 Light:  TEXCOORD0, float3 Normal : TEXCOORD1) :COLOR0
{
    return Diffuse_color * Diffuse_intens * dot(Normal, Light);
}

/* =============== ТЕХНИКА =============== */
technique technique0 {
    pass p0 {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VS_Main();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS_Main();
    }
}
```

Метод отрисовки:

```
    Material material = new Material();
    material.Diffuse = Color.White;
    material.Ambient = Color.FromArgb(60, 60, 60);
    device.Material = material;

    device.Transform.World = Matrix.Identity;
    device.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(OffsetVector) * RotationMatrix;
    device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured.Format;
    device.SetTexture(0, MainTexture);

    #region Параметры шейдера
    effect.Technique = "technique0";
    effect.SetValue("world_matrix", device.Transform.World);
    effect.SetValue("view_matrix", device.Transform.View);
    effect.SetValue("proj_matrix", device.Transform.Projection);
    effect.SetValue("light_position", new float[3] { device.Lights[0].Position.X, device.Lights[0].Position.Y, device.Lights[0].Position.Z });
    effect.SetValue("Diffuse_intens", 1);
    effect.SetValue("Diffuse_color", device.Material.DiffuseColor);
    #endregion

    int numPasses = effect.Begin(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPasses; i++)
    {
        effect.BeginPass(i);
        device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, PrimitivesCount, Verts);
        effect.EndPass();
    }
    effect.End();

    device.SetTexture(0, null);
    device.Transform.World = Matrix.Identity;
```